# How to use Redux Sagas to load single object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I've been working on a react project, using redux and sagas.
So far I was able to create a structure where my component would dispatch an action requesting a list, then sagas takes this action and calls a function that would make the request to the backend. I then store this list on redux, and my component reads the list from redux.

Now I need to load a single object from backend. I thought about not using sagas for that request, but I guess it makes sense to make this request using sagas and storing this single object on redux.

**I can't figure how to make the rootSaga function accept to take my function with 'id' as parameter.**

To ilustrate the scenario, here is some code:

*this is the root saga function, it would make the API request and call the action to store on redux*

```
export function* loadEvent({ id: number }) {
  try {
    console.log('load single event');

    yield put(loadEventSuccess(event));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(loadFailure());
  }
}
```

*This is the rootSaga function that is supposed to get the action I dispatched and trigger my saga function. The problems is that it does not accept me to call the function with a parameter. Even if I could, I don't know how to pass a parameter to it.*

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  return yield all([
    takeLatest(EventsTypes.LOAD_EVENT_REQUEST, loadEvent),
  ]);
}
```

Of course, before all that there is an action I dispatched from my function component.

Another thing that has been confusing me is if the approach I've been using is ok. I could make this request from my function component and store the data in its state. By doing that I wouldn't involve redux nor sagas. Would that make sense?

Comment: Nearly all my sagas in my project use parameters. What error do you get ? is the ID undefined ? in this case, please show your action creator that returns an action of type LOAD_EVENT_REQUEST

Comment: Yeah, I found out I forgot to put the payload in my action. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is completely right as you should try to make every api call throw your sagas, but you just made a small mistake

```
function* loadEvent({ payload }) {
const { id } = payload;
  try {
    const response = yield call(api.get, `localhost:4000/api/${id}`);
    yield put(loadEventSuccess(event));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(loadFailure());
  }
};
```

You also don't need to export the generator functions, and in my example I'm simulating an api get call using **axios**. And don't forget to `import { call } from "redux-saga/effects";`

Comment: Thanks! I found out my 'LOAD_EVENT_REQUEST' action was accepting a parameter, but it was not sending that parameter in the payload. After doing that I was able to get that value in my generator function just like you showed. However, I'm using Typescript, so it asks for a type. Would you happen to know what type should 'payload' be?

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you should use payload as type object, but I'm not a hundred percent sure about that, because I don't have much experience with typescript. I hope I helped you :)